# How to write to a new csv row with each loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm sure there's a very basic solution to this but wasn't able to figure it out from docs. Basically, I'm doing a loop and doing an API call with each loop, then trying to write the data to a csv. However, every loop is overwriting the first row on the csv, and I want each loop to append the data to the subsequent row in the csv.

```
while counter >= 1 
    high_temp = method_that_gets_high_temperature
    counter = counter - 1

    CSV.open("summer_temp.csv", "w") do |row|
        row << [month, day, year, high_temp]
    end

end
```

Comment: Do you mean that on every iteration of the 'while' loop the CSV file is truncated? That is because you provide 'w' (write and truncate) to CSV.open. If you want to append, you should pass 'a' instead. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode

Answer (score 0):

This is because you provide 'w' (write and truncate) to CSV.open. If you want to append, you should pass 'a' instead. See ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode

Answer (score 0):

Let's let

```
def api
  @api ||= [['woof', 'meow'], ['devoted', 'aloof'], ['1 life', '9 lives']].cycle
  @api.next
end
```

simulate your API:

```
api #=> ["woof", "meow"] 
api #=> ["devoted", "aloof"] 
api #=> ["1 life", "9 lives"] 
api #=> ["woof", "meow"] 
...
```

*ad infinitum*. See [Array#cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle). Before we forget, reset `@api`: `@api = nil`.

We can then write the following.

```
require 'csv'

def doit(fname, headers, n)
  CSV.open(fname, "w") do |csv|
    csv << headers
    n.times { csv << api }
  end
end
```

Try it:

```
doit('test.csv', ['dogs', 'cats'], 2)

puts File.read('test.csv') 
dogs,cats
woof,meow
devoted,aloof
```